# Production log file is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, I'm getting some errors when I upload my app. However, my log file is completely blank. Locally, my production.log is completely blank when running in production mode. I have no idea why, as `config.log_level = :debug`

I'm running my app locally in production mode with these settings:

```
App::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

#  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
#  config.assets.digest = true
#  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
   config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
   config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
#  config.assets.compile = true

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :authentication => :plain,
    :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
    :port => x,
    :domain => "x",
    :user_name => "x",
    :password => "x"
  }

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.log_level = :debug
end
```

Just browsing around my app produces nothing in the logs.

Comment: With your own config file, remove commented lines to aid your debugging efforts.

Comment: Are you running webrick or some other server?

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis I've tried puma and webrick